# Copying and formating a child dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, copy

I'm trying to use a dictionary of dictionaries to facilitate some reporting. The dictionaries contain some template with format variables; I'd like to populate these.

This is a self-contain minimalist example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
ISSUES = {
    'BIG_ISSUE': {
        'code': 1,
        'title': 'Something interesting',
        'detail': 'This is the affected domain {domain}'
    },
    'OTHER_ISSUE': {
        'code': 2,
        'title': 'Some other issue',
        'detail': 'Blah.'
    }
}

domain = 'foo.bar'
issue = ISSUES['BIG_ISSUE']
issue['detail'].format(domain=domain)

print(issue)
```

This is the output of the above:

```
{'code': 1, 'title': 'Something interesting', 'detail': 'This is the affected domain {domain}'}
```

Note that above, the `{domain}` was not formatted in the output.

This is the expected result I'm looking for:

```
{'code': 1, 'title': 'Something interesting', 'detail': 'This is the affected domain foo.bar'}
```

I believe this is due to strings being immutable? I tried following some of the examples on SO and tried using `dict()` and `import copy; copy.deepcopy()` but that gave me the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `issue['detail'].format(domain=domain)` returns new string. You get this string and then do nothing with it.
If you want to change the value for the key, you should use

```
issue['detail'] = issue['detail'].format(domain=domain)
```